# iOS Background task (NSThread) dies

Tags: background, asihttprequest, nsthread, cllocation

Some days ago I posted a question about NSThread. Finally I managed to make it run in background every minute.

The aim of the app is to get the location and then call to a webservice to update it on a server with ASIHTTPRequest every X minutes.

The code:

```
- (void)threadEntryPoint:(ActualizarPosicionGPS2AppDelegate *)paramSender{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    while([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled] == NO){
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:60.0f];
        if ([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled] == NO &&
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] != DBL_MAX) {
            [self hacerCosasBackground];
        }
    }

    [pool release];
}
```

hacerCosasBackground calls to the locationManager updating it's position and then uploads the position to a server.

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadEntryPoint:) toTarget:self withObject:self];


-(void) endTaskWidthIdentifier:(NSNumber *)paramIdentifier{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [paramIdentifier integerValue];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:identifier];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSNumber *backgroundTask = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endTaskWidthIdentifier:) withObject:backgroundTask waitUntilDone:YES];
        self.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```

However, the NSThread dies about 10 minutes later of closing the app. I've registered in the info.plist the 'UIBackgroundModes' location.
I also read about startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges but I want to make my app very configurable (the user will be able to set the how often they want to update the location, etc.) and I understood that that method updates every 500m (that's not good, I want to update the location more often).

What could I do? Any help please?

Thank you very much!